# Why is my program saying that the length function is not in my std library?

Tags: c++, getline

My program is saying that the function length() is not in the standard library and is producing an error that does not let me run my code

I have tried to place two different libraries into the #include statements. I then tried to place the length function on different variables but the same error occurs.

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream out_file_DOI("declaration_of_independence.txt");
    if (out_file_DOI.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(cout, out_file_DOI, i))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            cout << line.length();   //error is on this line...
            i++;
        }
        out_file_DOI.close();
      }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
    }
    //creates the declaration file
    out_file_DOI.open("declaration_of_independence.txt");
  }
```

I expect the code to run and show the proper results (proper results being the program encrypting the file (Declaration of Independence).

Comment: can you explicitly use `std::string line;`?

Comment: Copying and pasting an error message is usually more useful than paraphrasing it. After all, paraphrasing uses your understanding of the situation, and if you understood the situation perfectly, you wouldn't need to ask for help.

Comment: I suspect the includes themselves are important information for answering the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including any includes or anything you might have above `main`. You appear to have an erroneous extra bracket too

Comment: What happens if you replace it with `size()` Still the same error?

Comment: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) has no signature that supports your use. As said, you need to post a complete example of your code and the error so as the lines match up.

Comment: I can't reproduce the described problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/McE9LalWREHGGQnO. Your code has some other errors but not what you described.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if u wanna read a line by line from the file to “line” string,

```
getline(out_file_DOI, line);
```

Comment: A completely unrelated issue. Asker is trying to figure out why the compiler rejects a call to [`std::string::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)